# Prove that for all $a \in N$ and $b \in K, aba^{−1}b ^{−1} \in N \bigcap K.$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and let $N$ and $K$ be normal subgroups of $G.$

All I can think of to start is by noting that if $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ then for all $x \in G, xax^{-1} \subseteq N.$ Also if $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ then for all $x \in G, xbx^{-1} \subseteq K.$ Not sure how to work with this to show $aba^{−1}b ^{−1} \in N \bigcap K.$

Comment: Note that $aba^{−1}b ^{−1}=(aba^{−1})b ^{−1}=a(ba^{−1}b ^{−1})$, then use the two normalities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, do the maths as follows

$$n\in N,\,k\in K\;:\;\; n^{-1}k^{-1}nk=\begin{cases}\overbrace{(n^{-1}k^{-1}n)}^{\in K}k\in KK=K\\{}\\n^{-1}\overbrace{(k^{-1}nk)}^{\in N}\in NN=N\end{cases}\implies n^{-1}k^{-1}nk\in N\cap K $$